# IDA + IDA Python on wine/Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ida

I want to use the windows version of IDA on linux using wine. However, Ubuntu run IDA pro results can not load idapython, the lower left corner has been shown IDC.IDA pro shows as follows:

```
LoadLibrary(Z:\opt\ida68\plugins\python.plw) error: Module not found.
Z:\opt\ida68\plugins\python.plw: can't load file.
```

The terminal shows:

```
err:module:import_dll Library python27.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\opt\\ida68\\plugins\\python.plw") not found.
```

Tried to download `python27.dll` and `msvcr90.dll` into the IDA root directory but that did not solve the problem.

Download a python27.dll online into the IDA root directory, the problem is fixed.

And then the bomb box suggested:'import site failed!'.

Add the environment variable to / etc / profile:

export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7 $PYTHONPATH'.

IDAPython runs normally.

However,a warning window pops up show as:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Download a python27.dll online into the IDA root directory, the problem is fixed.
And then the bomb box suggested:'import site failed!'

Answer (score 1):

Python library may need other files than the `python27.dll` to run. Try installing it properly by Wine:

```
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.msi
wine msiexec /i python-2.7.15.msi
```

Then follow the installation wizard.

It's not necessary to install all the components, just the core Python suffices.